# Which script font does Wendy Gladney use for her logo?

Tags: font-identification

[image: Wendy's Logo]

<sup>As seen on http://www.wendygladney.com</sup>

Can you please identify the cursive/script font in this image?

Answer (score 4):

Andrew's answer is correct, *but*...

It is a mixture of **Beautiful Caps ES (Bold)**

[image: Beautiful Caps ES (Bold)]

and **Beautiful ES (Italic)**

[image: Beautiful ES (Italic)]

To determine this, I found a [PDF](http://www.wendygladney.com/WE_Media_Kit.pdf) on her [website](http://www.wendygladney.com/about_wendy.html) that features the logo. Sometimes you can get lucky with an embedded font not being outlined.

Illustrator will tell you all the fonts you need if you open the PDF:

[image: whiny Illustrator]

> `The font BeautifulCapsES,Bold is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.`
>
> `The font BeautifulES,Italic is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.`
>
> `The font DaunPenh is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.`
>
> `The font FuturaBT-Heavy is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.`

Then just select the text that looks weird and see what font it should be, or you can use the ***Find Font*** dialogue to cycle through where these fonts are used (fonts denoted with an asterisk are the problem fonts)

[image: Find Font]

---

<sup>*</sup>**These fonts are just likely just stolen and re-named. I would advise against using them for a commercial project!**

Comment: So it's actually a rip-off of an Adobe font!

Comment: @AndrewLeach indeed :) (I've updated my answer to note that). The legality of these fonts is ...questionable. I actually just thought they were _really_ similar, but you're right! There's quite clearly something shady going on here

Answer (score 3):

You can use [What the Font](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) for this sort of thing, provided that you separate the letters (the swash W presents a bit of a challenge with that!)

It's **[Bickham Script Pro](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/bickham-script-mm/regular/)** — the clincher is the lower-case **y**. The [glyph list](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/bickham-script-mm/regular/glyphs.html?render=webfont) includes the swash W.

[image: Bickham Script Pro from My Fonts]